# How to delete a df row based on an index base?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have this df:

```
question=pd.DataFrame()
question['Area']=['Miami','Miami','NYC','Dallas','Dallas','Dallas']
question['Venues']=['Margaritas','Salsa Club','Ginos','7Eleven','Laser Tag','Starbucks']
question
```

```
    Area    Venues
0   Miami   Margaritas
1   Miami   Salsa Club
2   NYC     Ginos
3   Dallas  7Eleven
4   Dallas  Laser Tag
5   Dallas  Starbucks
```

I want to drop every Area with less than 3 venues, for that I get the indexes using groupby:
Input

```
index_names=question.groupby('Area').count()[question.groupby('Area').count()['Venues']<3].index
index_names
```

Output

```
Index(['Miami', 'NYC'], dtype='object', name='Area')
```

How can I now delete all rows in which 'Area' corresponds to the values stored in index_names?
I've tried this:

```
for i in index_names
  question.drop(question['Area']==index_names[i].index, inplace=True)
```

Getting the following error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-113-f64dcfe81656>", line 1
    for i in index_names
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You are missing a colon `for i in index_names:`

Answer (score 1):

First, you miss `:` at the end of `for` row:

```
for i in index_names:
#                   ^--- this
```

Second, you can just use `isin`:

```
question[~question['Area'].isin(index_names)]
```